# NoReverseMatch with Django urls

Tags: javascript, django, django-views, django-urls

I have an `"NoReverseMatch at ∕ "` eception with exception value:

```
Reverse for 'listEvents' with keyword arguments '{'values': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['events/events\\/(?P<values>[^/]+)\\/$']
```

The odd thing is that I do not recognize this part: `events/events\\/(?P<values>[^/]+)\\/$`

My JScode:

```
var categories ="{% url 'events:listEvents' values=string %}";
```

where `string` is a SQL query.

This is my URL

```
  path('events/<str:values>/', views.showRequestedEvents, name='listEvents')
```

And this is my view

```
def showRequestedEvents(request, values):
    events = serialize('geojson', Event.objects.raw(values))
    return HttpResponse(events, content_type='json')
```

I know that it is pretty basic and I have seen similar questions has been asked a lot, yet even after searching for about 2 hr I haven't figured it out, so help!

Please...

Comment: `{'values': ''}` is telling you that `values` is not set in the template context. ``NoReverseMatch at  /` is telling you that it's the index view for `/` that is causing the problem.

Comment: To help you any further we probably need to see your `urls.py` and the full stacktrace of the error, and also which URL you are trying to access

Comment: That isn't your view. The relevant view must be rendering the template that that tag is on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it "fixed". Looks like python or django don't like JavaScript variables so I could not put it directly into the url but had to use replace like this:

```
var categories ="{% url 'events:listEvents' 12345 %}".replace(/12345/,string);
```